# Can I set the border-radius for Raised Button?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I've tried to set the border-radius like this :

```
const styles = {
   btn:{
         height: 30,
         fontSize: 11,
         borderRadius: 50
   }
}
```

It didn't work. I've read the documentation but can't find the answer.

Comment: which version are you using?

Comment: @DhavalJardosh `"material-ui": "^0.20.0"`

Comment: edit in buttonStyle and set borderRadius. You will be able to do it. If I can get a codepen I can do it for you.

Comment: Thank you @DhavalJardosh... I solved it by added buttonStyle and set the borderRadius in there...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

## Update (June 2020)

With the newer versions of material-ui, there no need for both props `style` and `buttonStyle` only `style` will be enough also, `RaisedButton` [has been dropped](https://material-ui.com/guides/migration-v0x/#raised-button) with the migration from 0.x to 1.x being replaced now by `variant="contained"`.
Here is a modern version of the code in the original answer

```js
<Button variant="contained" color="secondary" style={{ borderRadius: 50 }}/>
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/rounded-raised-button-w86o8?file=/index.js:0-361

## Original Answer (April 2018)

This works for me

```
 <RaisedButton secondary buttonStyle={{ borderRadius: 50 }} style={{borderRadius:50}}>FF</RaisedButton>
```

Give both the `style` and `buttonStyle`. style covers the parent `div` inline styles

https://codesandbox.io/s/7o39499v9x

Answer (score 4):

for mui v5 you do it with the [`sx`](https://mui.com/system/the-sx-prop/#borders) property:

```
<Button sx={{ borderRadius: 12.5 }} />
```

> The borderRadius properties multiples the value it receives by the `theme.shape.borderRadius`.

```
const theme = createTheme({
  shape: {
    borderRadius: 2,    // defaults to 4
  },
  palette: {...},
});
```